# QFile: directory not found

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I need to write a console application that takes a file, it opens it, and then it calls another procedure based on the information inside the text file.
The only problem is that `QFile::errorString()` returns:

> No such file or directory.

I have been using this implementation in all the programs I had to, and yes, the file exists at that directory.

The code is:

```
QFile fileName("D:/file.txt");
QString read_from_file;
if(fileName.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QTextStream in(&fileName);
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        read_from_file = in.readLine();
        qDebug()<<read_from_file;
    }
    fileName.close();
 }
qDebug()<<fileName.errorString();
```

Comment: You have different variable names - `fileName` and `description_file`. Typo?

Comment: @kefir500 Yes, let me modify the question, I have already changed it in my code. Thanks.

Comment: does relative dir path to the same file works fine?

Comment: Try changing it to: `QFile fileName(QDir::toNativeSeperators("D:/file.text");`

Comment: @DawidPi what do you mean by relative dir path?

Comment: @Nicholas Smith Still nothing :/

Comment: What does `QFile("D:/file.txt").exists()` return? Also, is your file present in the `qDebug() << QDir("D:/").entryList()` output?

Comment: @kefir500 , this is the dumbest thing ever, but QDir("D:/").entryList() 's output contains "file.txt.txt". Could you please answer the question so I can select your answer as the good one? Many many thanks :D It looks like I forgot that Windows 10 hides the extension of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file really exists.

- [`QFile::exists("D:/file.txt")`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#exists) – This will return `true` if the file exists.
- [`QDir("D:/").entryList()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList-1) – This will return the list of the files and directories located at the specified path; the needed file should be in the list.

---

As you pointed out in the comments, the problem was the [hidden file extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7) on Windows.

> 1. Open Folder Options by clicking the *Start* button, clicking *Control Panel*, clicking *Appearance and
>      Personalization*, and then clicking *Folder Options*.
> 2. Click the *View* tab, and then *Advanced settings* <...>
>
>    - To show file name extensions, clear the *Hide extensions for known file
>        types* check box, and then click *OK*.